# Verify the identity $\sin 3x + \sin x = 4\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the identity: $$\sin 3x + \sin x = 4\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$$

All I've done is this, and I don't know where to go from here:

$$4\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$$

$$ = 4(\sin x - \sin^3 x)$$

$$ = (4\sin x)(1 - \sin^2 x)$$

$$ = (4/\sin x)(\cos^2 x)$$

Am I on the right track??

Comment: use the identity $sin3x=3sinx-4sin^{3}x$

Comment: Put some serious effort into your questions before posting. Please don't post a new one every half an hour.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the fact I try a problem, get stuck, ask for help.  I didn't realize it was a bad thing to post questions.

Comment: It isn't a problem to ask questions or seek help. However, you have asked a number of quite similar questions on trigonometric identities in a short period of time. You need to show you have learned something by thinking about previous solutions, otherwise people will think they are just doing your work for you, and that you are more interested in answering the questions than learning the techniques for solving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need the "angle-addition formula" for sine, since you probably aren't expected to know "multiple-angle formulas".  (You *will* need the "*double*-angle formulas"...)

$$ \sin 3x \  + \  \sin x \ = \ \sin(2x + x ) \ + \ \sin x $$

$$ = \ (\sin 2x  \ \cos x \ + \ \cos 2x \ \sin x) \ + \ \sin x $$

$$ = \ [ \ (2  \sin x \ \cos x \ \cdot \cos x) \ + \ (1 \ - \ 2 \sin^2 x) \ \sin x ] \ + \ \sin x  $$

$$ = \ [ \ (2  \sin x \ \cos^2 x ) \ + \ (1 \ - \ 2 \sin^2 x) \ \sin x ] \ + \ \sin x  \ = \  [ \ (2  \sin x \cdot [1 - \sin^2 x] \ ) \ + \ (1 \ - \ 2 \sin^2 x) \ \sin x ] \ + \ \sin x \ . $$

You can probably take it from there.

Answer (score 4):

[image: sin(3x)+sin(x)=4sin(x)-4sin^3(x)]

$$ 4 \sin(x) (1-\sin^2(x))=4\sin(x)\cos^2(x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(x)=\sin(3x)+\sin(x) $$

Comment: Note that the last step here may be justified as a [product to sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) type identity.  This might be worth adding to your Answer.

Comment: thanks for your information and advice

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin 3x + \sin x = 4\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$$

which is the same as writing,

$$\sin 3x = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$$

You can either assume this standard identity, and we are done. Or we can try to prove this.

We have $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\implies e^{3ix}=\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)$

But $e^{3ix}=(e^{ix})^3$

$$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3 = \cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)$$

$$\cos^3(x)+3i\sin(x)\cos^2(x)+3i^2\sin^2(x)\cos(x)+i^3\sin^3(x)= \cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)$$

The imaginary parts must be equal, which gives us

$$3\sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x))-\sin^3(x)=\sin(3x)$$

$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)=\sin(3x)$$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

$$\sin3x+\sin x=2\sin2x\cos x=2\cos x(2\sin x\cos x)=4\sin x\cos^2x$$
$$=4\sin x(1-\sin^2x)$$